# Perform script exactly one time

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

In the some Spreadsheet I have function (google app script):

```
function sayHello() {
    Browser.msg("Hello!");
}
```

And I bind it to open trigger:

```
function onOpen(e) {
    sayHello();
}
```

Ok, trigger performs when spreadsheet opens or updates. But how to make sayHello() runs only one time (at the very first opening) and not at each opening?

Comment: Change  simple `onOpen` to a installable trigger. Then programmatically delete that trigger on first execution using `ScriptApp` trigger ID.

Comment: Do you mean once a day?

Comment: Every time that the code runs, get today's date.  Then get the date from the last time that the code ran.  Use Properties Service to store the date when the code completed.  If the date stored is before today's date, then update the saved date in Properties Service, otherwise halt the code.

Comment: If you use use “user” Properties then it will happen one time for each user.

Comment: @I'-'I, your suggestion look like what I need